# Different result in changing precedence of operator

Tags: c++

I am analysis why a.b /c and  a/b.c gives different result for a different cases.
Is someone explain me the reason except than the precedence of operator.

int d= a*b/c;

int e=a/b*c;

cout<< d<< " " << e;

Comment: What data-types? What values? In what code context?

Comment: Why would you expect them to produce the same results in the first place? `a*b/c` and `a/b*c` are very different things.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication and division operators do not precede each other. The left-to-right association of multiplicative expressions becomes significant in this case.

It is simply a mathematical fact that `a × b ÷ c ≠ a ÷ b × c` in most cases.

For example:

```
  10 × 5 ÷ 2
= 50 ÷ 2
= 25

  10 ÷ 5 × 2
= 2 × 2
= 4
```

Also see:

- [C++ Operator Precedence - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: A link in the answer to [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) is always nice.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence of product and division is the same. However when they are mixed they are evaluated in pairs from left to right. For instance:

D = a × b ÷ c

Is evaluated as: (a × b) ÷ c

While

D = b ÷ c × a

Is evaluated as (b ÷ c) × a

Mathematically both are equivalent. However in a programming language they might be different. For instance if a, b and c are integers, the division involved is the integer division.

So if a, b and c are greater than 1 and c does not divide exactly the product a × b, then

a × b ÷ c != b ÷ c × a

Since integer division is discarding different amounts on each side of the equation.

Finally, the specific sample expressions that you provide will produce different results even using real numbers since they are mathematically different.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 concepts related to this matter, **Operator Precedence** and **Associative Order**.

When the operators used have different precedence, Operator Precedence comes into play.

But when the operators have same precedence, compiler's associative order comes into play.

Consider this expression,

```
a*b/c
```

If the compiler reads it from left-to-right, which is **Left-To-Right Associativity**, then the expression is evaluated as,

```
(a*b)/c
```

If the compiler reads it from right-to-left, which is **Right-To-Left Associativity**, then the expression is evaluated as,

```
a*(b/c)
```

Therefore, the expressions

```
a*b/c and a/b*c
```

would be evaluated differently because the compiler is going to either read both from left-to-right or from right-to-left.

In both the cases, the expressions will be evaluated differently.